# Change edit rights on an item based on task outcome

Tags: workflow, tasks, task-list

I have a workflow set up that is associated with a custom user list. Users can add, but also edit these items in a list. However, what I want to achieve its that users can edit an item in a list up until a task reaches a certain outcome (e.g. "submitted to user x"). If "submitted to user x" equals "yes", change permissions for item x.

How can this be achieved?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- You should create a page for user rights, and then give the user rights condition on the task form button.
- You should check the condition in the task form button.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this. I need to set the permissions on the item itself, not on a page I assume.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about SPD workflows but you can certainly do this in Nintex workflow by using the Set Permissions action based on your condition.